# Как проверить что родитель Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, наследование, usercontrol, controls

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать уникальную проверку, что например ellipse дочерний по отношению к Grid ? ...

```
    private void Window_PreviewMouseDown_2(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Source as Control).Parent is Grid == true){
          // Ура, наш control или ellipse или usercontrol внутри grid'а
        }
    }
```

Всё кажется легко, но когда в `e.Source` лежит не стандартный `System.Windows.Controls`, а например какой нибудь из `System.Windows.Shapes` то программа вылетает из-за несоответствия типов, а если будет пользовательский контрол, то я вообще боюсь себе представить что там будет твориться :)

Comment: Странно, обычно вам не должно хотеться знать, в каком объекте находится ваш объект. Какую настоящую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: действительно, странно. Между элипсом и гридом могут быть другие позиционирующие контейнеры, например StackPanel. А с другой стороны среди родительских контенеров любого контрола на форме всегда можно найти грид, и даже не один ))), То есть, ближе к алгоритмам - искать нужно не непосредственного предка, а в цикле - выше и выше, пока не найдем. А с другой стороны - найдем грид всегда, потому что они везде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка должна быть такой:

```
(ellipse.Parent != null) && (ellipse.Parent is Grid)
```

(Кстати, у эллипса нет свойства `Source`, так что непонятно, как это у вас компилируется.)

---

Для вашего случая покатит просто

```
var fe = (FrameworkElement)(e.Source);
if ((fe.Parent != null) && (fe.Parent is Grid))
{
    ...
```

---

Обновление: Как подсказывает @Igor, для случая `fe.Parent == null` проверка `fe.Parent is Grid` вернёт `false`, так что первая проверка не нужна. Итого:

```
var fe = (FrameworkElement)(e.Source);
if (fe.Parent is Grid)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Не, так зато не будет работать если вместо ellipse будет button, я так уже делал.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: (1) В вопросе вообще-то спрашивается именно про `Ellipse`, но (2) Этот код должен работать и если тип переменной `ellipse` — `Button`.

Comment: я просто хотел узнать есть ли какой нибудь уникальный тип, с которым можно было бы сделать `((e.Source as SUPERTYPE).Parent is Grid == true)` и всё это бы работало и с пользовательскими контролам и со стандартными(System.Windows.Controls) и не стандартными (System.Windows.Shapes)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Не-не, если вы пишете `as`, результат может быть `null`.

Comment: Вообще идеально было бы если можно было бы сделать `if ((e.Source).Parent is Grid == true)` :D

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) на свойство `Parent` у `Ellipse` написано: «(Inherited from FrameworkElement.)»

Comment: О вот он тот самый идеальный тип FrameworkElement, огромное спасибо :)))))

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD - `(fe.Parent != null)` не нужен

Comment: @Igor: Почему не нужен? Если у вас элемент отсоединился от визуального дерева (например, в результате работы другого подписчика на тот же event), то у вас `fe.Parent` таки будет `null`, и код крешнется. Или не крешнется, но проверка `fe.Parent is Grid` выдаст `true`.

Comment: @VladD - наверное я неправильно понимаю какие-то базовые вещи, но до Вашего ответа я готов был держать пари, что если `fe.Parent` - `null`, то `fe.Parent is Grid` вернет `false`

Comment: @Igor: Да, действительно, вы правы. Спасибо! Исправлю код в ответе.